# Number of Validator nodes on Eth2

Tags: eth-2.0

How can I estimate the number of validator nodes that operate on Eth2? Often ~200k are reported but these can't be the actual number of nodes running, right? Probably just a lot of people pooling their funds on a single node.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing the [Eth2 launchpad](https://launchpad.ethereum.org/en/) reports 8,322,105 ETH staked.

Given that, to become a validator, one must stake 32 ETH.

8,322,105 / 32 = 260,065 which is not too far from the reported number of validator nodes of 250,390.

You might be confusing a staking pool with the validator node. Yes most people don't have 32 ETH or more, but almost all staking pools have (much) more than that.

With X ethereum stacked in a pool by any number of users, the pool can run X / 32 validator nodes. But it does not mean that it's ran by X / 32 distinct machines or individuals.

You can run many validator nodes on a single machine. PoS doesn't require nearly as much computational resources as PoW.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I estimate the number of validator nodes that operate on Eth2? Often ~200k are reported but these can't be the actual number of nodes running, right?

The reporter "validators" number is validator keys, not validator node. The validator nodes are a subset of Ethereum peer-to-peer nodes that's around ~10,000 as writing of this.